# Mellin transform of $\frac{\sinh (\pi x)}{(\cosh (\pi x)-1)^3}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I would like to know if the following holds true
$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^{s-1} \sinh (\pi  x)}{(\cosh (\pi x)-1)^3} \, dx= \frac{1}{3} \pi ^{-s} (\zeta (4-s)-\zeta (2-s)) \Gamma (s)$$  and a route to prove it.

Comment: Yes, it is. $\phantom{}$

Comment: Yes, and it's also quite trivial.

Comment: Antonio : what interest us is the maths, i.e. the derivation, not if it is true or not. The problem is that you don't look at the derivation (the answers to all your question) and you don't even try to understand them. So now stop asking all those formulas, and explain what you want to do (and what you want to understand in maths).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. One may expand the integrand then one is allowed to integrate termwise ($0<s<1$): $$ 
\begin{align} 
\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^{s-1} \sinh (\pi x)}{(\cosh (\pi  x)-1)^3} \, dx&=4\int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^{s-1}\left( e^{\pi  x}-e^{-\pi x}\right)}{\left( e^{\pi x}+e^{-\pi x}-2\right)^3} \, dx 
\\&= 4 \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^4-n^2}{12}e^{-n \pi x}\:dx
\\ & = 4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n^4-n^2}{12} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1} e^{-n \pi x}\:dx
\\ &= \frac13  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n^4-n^2)\frac{ \pi^{-s} \Gamma(s)}{n^s} 
 \\ &= \frac{1}{3} \pi ^{-s} (\zeta (4-s)-\zeta (2-s)) \Gamma (s) \end{align}$$ where we have used the standard [integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) of the Euler gamma function.

Comment: Great! +1 from me because I was writing exactly the same (with all the steps) but you have been faster lol

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}\sinh(\pi x)}{\left(\cosh(\pi x)-1\right)^3}\;dx &= \int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}\left(\frac{e^{\pi x}-e^{-\pi x}}2\right)}{\left(\frac{e^{\pi x}+e^{-\pi x}}2-1\right)^3}\;dx \\
&= 4\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}\left(e^{\pi x}-e^{-\pi x}\right)}{\left(e^{\pi x}+e^{-\pi x}-2\right)^3}\;dx \\
&= 4\int_0^{\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}\left(e^{-2\pi x}-e^{-4\pi x}\right)}{\left(1-e^{-\pi x}\right)^6}\;dx \\
&= 4\int_0^{\infty}x^{s-1}\left(e^{-2\pi x}-e^{-4\pi x}\right)\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+5}5 e^{-n\pi x}\right]\;dx \\
&= 4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+5}5 \int_0^{\infty}x^{s-1}\left(e^{-(n+2)\pi x}-e^{-(n+4)\pi x}\right)\;dx \\
&= 4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+5}5 \left[\int_0^{\infty}x^{s-1}e^{-(n+2)\pi x}\;dx - \int_0^{\infty}x^{s-1}e^{-(n+4)\pi x}\;dx\right] \\
\end{align*}$$ = 4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+5}5 \left[\frac1{((n+2)\pi)^s}\int_0^{\infty}((n+2)\pi x)^{s-1}e^{-(n+2)\pi x}\;(n+2)\pi\;dx - \frac1{((n+4)\pi)^s}\int_0^{\infty}((n+4)\pi x)^{s-1}e^{-(n+4)\pi x}\;(n+4)\pi\;dx\right] $$\begin{align*}
&= 4\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+5}5 \left[\frac1{((n+2)\pi)^s}\int_0^{\infty}u^{s-1}e^{-u}\;du - \frac1{((n+4)\pi)^s}\int_0^{\infty}u^{s-1}e^{-u}\;du\right] \\
&= \frac{4\Gamma(s)}{\pi^s}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+5}5 \left[\frac1{(n+2)^s} - \frac1{(n+4)^s}\right] \\
&= \frac{4\Gamma(s)}{\pi^s}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\binom{n+3}5-\binom{n+1}5\right]\frac1{n^s} \\
&= \frac{4\Gamma(s)}{\pi^s}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)n(n-1) - (n+1)n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{120n^s} \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(s)}{30\pi^s}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)((n+2)(n+3) - (n-2)(n-3))}{n^s} \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(s)}{30\pi^s}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n+1)n(n-1)(10n)}{n^s} \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(s)}{3\pi^s}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^4-n^2}{n^s} \\
&= \frac{\Gamma(s)}{3\pi^s}\left(\zeta(s-4) - \zeta(s-2)\right)\;\blacksquare
\end{align*}